# Render the unordered list in bottom to top fashion

Tags: html, css, webkit

How to render the unordered list in bottom to top fashion.

I want to put specifications in the list such that first element is shown at the given position. Second item is shown at the top of the first item. Third item is shown at the top of second 
item and so on. The list should grow from bottom(first element) to top(last element) keeping the first element fixed at given position. The list is rendered by webkit.

I need to know what can be done in the below code to achieve this.

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-closed-captions-track-list ul,
video::-webkit-media-controls-closed-captions-track-list ul {

display: list-item;
list-style-type: disc;
position: relative;
right: 70px;
bottom: 50px;
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 3):

you can render the list from bottom to top using this method as well.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

<ul>
    <li>Item 1 </li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a Working Demo for you. http://jsbin.com/petokazi/1/edit

Comment: you can accept this answer by using green checkmak. so other people can get benefited.

Answer (score 1):

if list is

```
aaa
ggg
ccc
fff
```

apply css below

```
ul li 
{
  display: table-caption;
}
```

And result is

```
fff
ccc
ggg
aaa
```